# R Markdown plot will be out of area with `echo=FALSE`

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I use R Markdown to build a PDF, and I use `ggplot2` to plot. without hiding the code everything is right. (`ChickWeight` is a default dataset)

````
```{r}
ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(Time, weight, color = Diet)) + geom_point() + geom_path() + geom_boxplot(aes(group=Time))

```
````

[image]

But when I hide the code part with `{r echo=FALSE}` then the plot picture will be out of the box.
[image]

I'm looking for help to solve this.

Comment: Works fine on my machine.

Comment: Works also fine on my machine.

Comment: @TarJae and stefan. Thanks. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it just by an ENTER! I think it is a bug from R Markdown.

The problem occurs when the code is like this, without ***new line*** after the `texts`:

````
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```{r echo=FALSE}
ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(Time, weight, color = Diet)) + geom_point() + geom_path() + geom_boxplot(aes(group=Time))
```
````

It can be solved just by putting a ***new line*** after the `texts`. I mean like this:

````
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

```{r echo=FALSE}
ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(Time, weight, color = Diet)) + geom_point() + geom_path() + geom_boxplot(aes(group=Time))
```
````

Problem solved!

Comment: Well done! See here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949196/r-markdown-makes-custom-plot-disappear-if-i-set-echo-false> a similar issue.